# How can I make endpoint only with API using S3 only?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I make endpoint only with API. Is it practical to have only one JSON file and increase it all the time?

All I need is simple json data regularly increased with new records

```
{
"key":"value"
}
```

after 1 day i send another same+1 so now i have in json endpoint

```
{
"key": "value"
"key1: "value"
}
```

etc. Im  not sure should i use api gateway etc if i want only simple and easy way for this

Comment: You can just save the JSON in S3 and schedule a lamba function to add one key value pair per day.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you are trying to do. Could you please edit your question and add more details? For example, what do you mean by "make endpoint only with API"? Can you describe how you are wanting to access this information, and update this information? Are you simply saying that you want a URL that will return a JSON file?

Comment: My application has a function that sends back data that it provides in the form of
like { "data": "value"}
I want to have this data in one file so that later on it can be easily imported into e.g. google sheet (via api and also via csv). I'm looking for the easiest way for a newbie

Comment: Yes,i want an url file that will return the JSON value. Is there anything wrong with it if we're satisfied with the data in this form? I can have e.g. a thousand records and I don't know why I need a database? Are there any disadvantages of this?

Answer (score 0):

Add to S3, set a CloudWatch event scheduled event to trigger a Lambda. Then have the Lambda read the file contents and do the increment, then update.

As a recommendation I would say enable bucket versioning just in case you need to roll back.

Comment: But how do I add this data? My application has a function that sends data to Api Endpoint - is S3 such an endpoint?